# Showing directional derivative with the limit-definition

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate the directional derivative of $$f\colon \left(\exp{x}-1\right)\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}}$$
with the definition $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(f(a+h)-f(a)\right)$ at the point $a=(0,0)$.

So I get for $u=(x,y) \neq 0$ and $t\neq0$
$$\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t} = \frac{f(tu)}{t} = \frac{\left(\exp(tx)-1\right)\sqrt{\frac{(tx)^2}{(tx)^2+(ty)^2}}}{t} = \frac{\left(\exp(tx)-1\right)\left|tx\right|}{t\left|t\right|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{\left(\exp(tx)-1\right)\left|x\right|}{t\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

and now I am stuck. Mostly I'll get a limit of $0$ or $\infty$ or trying to take the limit of $t \to 0$ of the last equation yields something different than the solution which Mathematica yields:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left((\exp(hx)-1)\sqrt{\frac{(hx)^2}{(hx)^2+(hy)^2}}\right) = x \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}} .$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: There is no mistake. Use $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ and compute the limit
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{tx}-1}{t}$$

Comment: ah, thanks : $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{tx}-1}{t} = x$